# Rational Team Concert gwt plugin issue

Tags: gwt, plugins, rtc

I have installed Google Plugin for Eclipse 4.2. It's done normally, and I can see it in the list of installed plugins. But when I restarted the rtc, I can't find the plugin in the preferences window. The GDT Pulldown icon is also missing.

Unfortunately I can't use other eclipse or rtc versions because of company policy  :/.

Could anybody help me?